# Use LIKE operator on parameter

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to use the `like` operator on my parameter in Crystal Reports 2011. It should work for multiple check-ins. How can I accomplish something like the following code?

```
if ({?test}) like ("*ABC" ,"*KBJ" ,"*CDE") then 1 else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to only want strings that end in ABC, KBJ, or CDE. So try this:

```
(RIGHT({?test}, 3) = "ABC")
OR
(RIGHT({?test}, 3) = "KBJ")
OR
(RIGHT({?test}, 3) = "CDE")
```

Also it's worth noting that `IF yourConditionHere THEN 1 ELSE 0` is redundant. Simplify it to just `yourConditionHere` and it will return True or False.